# HTML 5 Drag & Drop

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Helllo I'm working on a project that requires drag and drop in HTML5.
It looks something like this: http://apps.sourcebits.com/cart543/index.html

But what I wanted is the drag item to remain in its position even after being dragged and also after dragging the image, i want the dropped image to be another image instead of the same one. Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance :) It will be great if somebody can find a tutorial on this for me or give me the codes for this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just look at this with jquery UI [follow link](http://jsfiddle.net/richapandey/awtmJ/4/)

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ helper: "clone" });
$( ".dropHere" ).droppable({
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $('<div></div>').text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
}
});
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the fiddle but is it possible to enable only 1 item in the box?? For example when i drag (drag 1) into the white box it shows up right? So when i drag (drag 2) into the white box i want it to replace (drag 1)

Comment: I also need it to be able to be drag out of the white box (delete/clear).. Will be so thankful if all these works out!

Comment: Thankyou!! This is what I needed!! But one last thing that I stated in my question earlier on, "after dragging the image, i want the dropped image to be another image instead of the same one. Is there any way to do it?"

Comment: Hello the fiddle that u gave me only works for text but not images.. Can you do one for images drag and drop instead of text? The rest is already solved :)

Comment: sorry for the delay .. pls see this now.. http://jsfiddle.net/richapandey/awtmJ/7/
I hope you are done after this .. :)

Comment: Hello there thanks!! That's what I need exactly! But I need one last final thing that I have stated many times.. Is it possible for me to drag and image and when I drop it, it becomes another image? Sorry for asking so much as I don't have much knowledge on js >_<

Comment: what exactly you mean by another image.. at the drop box or at there from where you are dragging.. ? pls clear my doubt.

Comment: when the image is dropped it turn into another image. Thats what I mean :) The moment it's dropped into the white box, change into another image..

Comment: Jos, I may not getting you in right way but it is working like you want it. I mean when i drag 1 img it shows up there and when I drag the 2 img, it replaces the 1st img with 2 img.

Comment: no what i mean is that when I drop the 1st image into the box it will turn into another image. I dont really have a working example to show you. Let's just say i got this watch which is watch 1 (topview). I drag the watch1 (topview) into the white box. And when i dropped it into the white box, It turns into another image which is also the same watch but an different image for eg watch 1 (sideview). Do you get it now?

Answer (score 0):

On a technical level HTML alone can't do this. It is strictly a markup language. However these days people refer to HTML5 as being the latest of all the web technolagies, and doesn't mean HTML 5.0.

That being said you will most likely need to use a client side language such as JQuery to create a drag and drop feature. And a Server Side Language such as PHP if you plan on the files that are being uploaded to the server. However if what your attempting to do is identical to the http://apps.sourcebits.com/cart543/index.html then you will most likely only need jquery.

Also it is worth mentioning that on my firefox I was able to right click on the page and save the page as something. WHen I opened it up on my local machine it worked exactly the same as it did on the site. So I would recomend doing that for sourcebits.com and then make the changes you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'll make your life easy. Modify the following as you need to. Just copy and paste

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>HTML5 Development | CSS3 Development | Shopping Cart Development | Cart 543</title>
<meta name="description" content="Cart543 is minimalistic shopping cart developed in HTML5 and CSS3">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 Development, CSS3 Development, eCommerce Development, Shopping Cart Development, Web Development, User Interface Design">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" media="screen">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
<script src="jquery-1.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" charset="utf-8">/* See license.txt for terms of usage */

/** reset styling **/

.firebugResetStyles {

    z-index: 2147483646 !important;

    top: 0 !important;

    left: 0 !important;

    display: block !important;

    border: 0 none !important;

    margin: 0 !important;

    padding: 0 !important;

    outline: 0 !important;

    min-width: 0 !important;

    max-width: none !important;

    min-height: 0 !important;

    max-height: none !important;

    position: fixed !important;

    transform: rotate(0deg) !important;

    transform-origin: 50% 50% !important;

    border-radius: 0 !important;

    box-shadow: none !important;

    background: transparent none !important;

    pointer-events: none !important;

    white-space: normal !important;

}



.firebugBlockBackgroundColor {

    background-color: transparent !important;

}



.firebugResetStyles:before, .firebugResetStyles:after {

    content: "" !important;

}

/**actual styling to be modified by firebug theme**/

.firebugCanvas {

    display: none !important;

}



/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

.firebugLayoutBox {

    width: auto !important;

    position: static !important;

}



.firebugLayoutBoxOffset {

    opacity: 0.8 !important;

    position: fixed !important;

}



.firebugLayoutLine {

    opacity: 0.4 !important;

    background-color: #000000 !important;

}



.firebugLayoutLineLeft, .firebugLayoutLineRight {

    width: 1px !important;

    height: 100% !important;

}



.firebugLayoutLineTop, .firebugLayoutLineBottom {

    width: 100% !important;

    height: 1px !important;

}



.firebugLayoutLineTop {

    margin-top: -1px !important;

    border-top: 1px solid #999999 !important;

}



.firebugLayoutLineRight {

    border-right: 1px solid #999999 !important;

}



.firebugLayoutLineBottom {

    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999 !important;

}



.firebugLayoutLineLeft {

    margin-left: -1px !important;

    border-left: 1px solid #999999 !important;

}



/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

.firebugLayoutBoxParent {

    border-top: 0 none !important;

    border-right: 1px dashed #E00 !important;

    border-bottom: 1px dashed #E00 !important;

    border-left: 0 none !important;

    position: fixed !important;

    width: auto !important;

}



.firebugRuler{

    position: absolute !important;

}



.firebugRulerH {

    top: -15px !important;

    left: 0 !important;

    width: 100% !important;

    height: 14px !important;

    background: url("data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%13%88%00%00%00%0E%08%02%00%00%00L%25a%0A%00%00%00%04gAMA%00%00%D6%D8%D4OX2%00%00%00%19tEXtSoftware%00Adobe%20ImageReadyq%C9e%3C%00%00%04%F8IDATx%DA%EC%DD%D1n%E2%3A%00E%D1%80%F8%FF%EF%E2%AF2%95%D0D4%0E%C1%14%B0%8Fa-%E9%3E%CC%9C%87n%B9%81%A6W0%1C%A6i%9A%E7y%0As8%1CT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AATE9%FE%FCw%3E%9F%AF%2B%2F%BA%97%FDT%1D~K(%5C%9D%D5%EA%1B%5C%86%B5%A9%BDU%B5y%80%ED%AB*%03%FAV9%AB%E1%CEj%E7%82%EF%FB%18%BC%AEJ8%AB%FA'%D2%BEU9%D7U%ECc0%E1%A2r%5DynwVi%CFW%7F%BB%17%7Dy%EACU%CD%0E%F0%FA%3BX%FEbV%FEM%9B%2B%AD%BE%AA%E5%95v%AB%AA%E3E5%DCu%15rV9%07%B5%7F%B5w%FCm%BA%BE%AA%FBY%3D%14%F0%EE%C7%60%0EU%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5JU%88%D3%F5%1F%AE%DF%3B%1B%F2%3E%DAUCNa%F92%D02%AC%7Dm%F9%3A%D4%F2%8B6%AE*%BF%5C%C2Ym~9g5%D0Y%95%17%7C%C8c%B0%7C%18%26%9CU%CD%13i%F7%AA%90%B3Z%7D%95%B4%C7%60%E6E%B5%BC%05%B4%FBY%95U%9E%DB%FD%1C%FC%E0%9F%83%7F%BE%17%7DkjMU%E3%03%AC%7CWj%DF%83%9An%BCG%AE%F1%95%96yQ%0Dq%5Dy%00%3Et%B5'%FC6%5DS%95pV%95%01%81%FF'%07%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%F8x%C7%F0%BE%9COp%5D%C9%7C%AD%E7%E6%EBV%FB%1E%E0(%07%E5%AC%C6%3A%ABi%9C%8F%C6%0E9%AB%C0'%D2%8E%9F%F99%D0E%B5%99%14%F5%0D%CD%7F%24%C6%DEH%B8%E9rV%DFs%DB%D0%F7%00k%FE%1D%84%84%83J%B8%E3%BA%FB%EF%20%84%1C%D7%AD%B0%8E%D7U%C8Y%05%1E%D4t%EF%AD%95Q%BF8w%BF%E9%0A%BF%EB%03%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%B8vJ%8E%BB%F5%B1u%8Cx%80%E1o%5E%CA9%AB%CB%CB%8E%03%DF%1D%B7T%25%9C%D5(%EFJM8%AB%CC'%D2%B2*%A4s%E7c6%FB%3E%FA%A2%1E%80~%0E%3E%DA%10x%5D%95Uig%15u%15%ED%7C%14%B6%87%A1%3B%FCo8%A8%D8o%D3%ADO%01%EDx%83%1A~%1B%9FpP%A3%DC%C6'%9C%95gK%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%20%D9%C9%11%D0%C0%40%AF%3F%EE%EE%92%94%D6%16X%B5%BCMH%15%2F%BF%D4%A7%C87%F1%8E%F2%81%AE%AAvzr%DA2%ABV%17%7C%E63%83%E7I%DC%C6%0Bs%1B%EF6%1E%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%80cr%9CW%FF%7F%C6%01%0E%F1%CE%A5%84%B3%CA%BC%E0%CB%AA%84%CE%F9%BF)%EC%13%08WU%AE%AB%B1%AE%2BO%EC%8E%CBYe%FE%8CN%ABr%5Dy%60~%CFA%0D%F4%AE%D4%BE%C75%CA%EDVB%EA(%B7%F1%09g%E5%D9%12%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00H%F6%EB%13S%E7y%5E%5E%FB%98%F0%22%D1%B2'%A7%F0%92%B1%BC%24z3%AC%7Dm%60%D5%92%B4%7CEUO%5E%F0%AA*%3BU%B9%AE%3E%A0j%94%07%A0%C7%A0%AB%FD%B5%3F%A0%F7%03T%3Dy%D7%F7%D6%D4%C0%AAU%D2%E6%DFt%3F%A8%CC%AA%F2%86%B9%D7%F5%1F%18%E6%01%F8%CC%D5%9E%F0%F3z%88%AA%90%EF%20%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%C0%A6%D3%EA%CFi%AFb%2C%7BB%0A%2B%C3%1A%D7%06V%D5%07%A8r%5D%3D%D9%A6%CAu%F5%25%CF%A2%99%97zNX%60%95%AB%5DUZ%D5%FBR%03%AB%1C%D4k%9F%3F%BB%5C%FF%81a%AE%AB'%7F%F3%EA%FE%F3z%94%AA%D8%DF%5B%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%8E%FB%F3%F2%B1%1B%8DWU%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*UiU%C7%BBe%E7%F3%B9%CB%AAJ%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5J%95*U%AAT%A9R%A5*%AAj%FD%C6%D4%5Eo%90%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5%86%AF%1B%9F%98%DA%EBm%BBV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%ADV%AB%D5j%B5Z%AD%D6%E4%F58%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%40%85%7F%02%0C%008%C2%D0H%16j%8FX%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82") repeat-x !important;

    border-top: 1px solid #BBBBBB !important;

    border-right: 1px dashed #BBBBBB !important;

    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important;

}



.firebugRulerV {

    top: 0 !important;

    left: -15px !important;

    width: 14px !important;

    height: 100% !important;

    background: url("data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0A%1A%0A%00%00%00%0DIHDR%00%00%00%0E%00%00%13%88%08%02%00%00%00%0E%F5%CB%10%00%00%00%04gAMA%00%00%D6%D8%D4OX2%00%00%00%19tEXtSoftware%00Adobe%20ImageReadyq%C9e%3C%00%00%06~IDATx%DA%EC%DD%D1v%A20%14%40Qt%F1%FF%FF%E4%97%D9%07%3BT%19%92%DC%40(%90%EEy%9A5%CB%B6%E8%F6%9Ac%A4%CC0%84%FF%DC%9E%CF%E7%E3%F1%88%DE4%F8%5D%C7%9F%2F%BA%DD%5E%7FI%7D%F18%DDn%BA%C5%FB%DF%97%BFk%F2%10%FF%FD%B4%F2M%A7%FB%FD%FD%B3%22%07p%8F%3F%AE%E3%F4S%8A%8F%40%EEq%9D%BE8D%F0%0EY%A1Uq%B7%EA%1F%81%88V%E8X%3F%B4%CEy%B7h%D1%A2E%EBohU%FC%D9%AF2fO%8BBeD%BE%F7X%0C%97%A4%D6b7%2Ck%A5%12%E3%9B%60v%B7r%C7%1AI%8C%BD%2B%23r%00c0%B2v%9B%AD%CA%26%0C%1Ek%05A%FD%93%D0%2B%A1u%8B%16-%95q%5Ce%DCSO%8E%E4M%23%8B%F7%C2%FE%40%BB%BD%8C%FC%8A%B5V%EBu%40%F9%3B%A72%FA%AE%8C%D4%01%CC%B5%DA%13%9CB%AB%E2I%18%24%B0n%A9%0CZ*Ce%9C%A22%8E%D8NJ%1E%EB%FF%8F%AE%CAP%19*%C3%BAEKe%AC%D1%AAX%8C*%DEH%8F%C5W%A1e%AD%D4%B7%5C%5B%19%C5%DB%0D%EF%9F%19%1D%7B%5E%86%BD%0C%95%A12%AC%5B*%83%96%CAP%19%F62T%86%CAP%19*%83%96%CA%B8Xe%BC%FE)T%19%A1%17xg%7F%DA%CBP%19*%C3%BA%A52T%86%CAP%19%F62T%86%CA%B0n%A9%0CZ%1DV%C6%3D%F3%FCH%DE%B4%B8~%7F%5CZc%F1%D6%1F%AF%84%F9%0F6%E6%EBVt9%0E~%BEr%AF%23%B0%97%A12T%86%CAP%19%B4T%86%CA%B8Re%D8%CBP%19*%C3%BA%A52huX%19%AE%CA%E5%BC%0C%7B%19*CeX%B7h%A9%0C%95%E1%BC%0C%7B%19*CeX%B7T%06%AD%CB%5E%95%2B%BF.%8F%C5%97%D5%E4%7B%EE%82%D6%FB%CF-%9C%FD%B9%CF%3By%7B%19%F62T%86%CA%B0n%D1R%19*%A3%D3%CA%B0%97%A12T%86uKe%D0%EA%B02*%3F1%99%5DB%2B%A4%B5%F8%3A%7C%BA%2B%8Co%7D%5C%EDe%A8%0C%95a%DDR%19%B4T%C66%82fA%B2%ED%DA%9FC%FC%17GZ%06%C9%E1%B3%E5%2C%1A%9FoiB%EB%96%CA%A0%D5qe4%7B%7D%FD%85%F7%5B%ED_%E0s%07%F0k%951%ECr%0D%B5C%D7-g%D1%A8%0C%EB%96%CA%A0%A52T%C6)*%C3%5E%86%CAP%19%D6-%95A%EB*%95q%F8%BB%E3%F9%AB%F6%E21%ACZ%B7%22%B7%9B%3F%02%85%CB%A2%5B%B7%BA%5E%B7%9C%97%E1%BC%0C%EB%16-%95%A12z%AC%0C%BFc%A22T%86uKe%D0%EA%B02V%DD%AD%8A%2B%8CWhe%5E%AF%CF%F5%3B%26%CE%CBh%5C%19%CE%CB%B0%F3%A4%095%A1%CAP%19*Ce%A8%0C%3BO*Ce%A8%0C%95%A12%3A%AD%8C%0A%82%7B%F0v%1F%2FD%A9%5B%9F%EE%EA%26%AF%03%CA%DF9%7B%19*Ce%A8%0C%95%A12T%86%CA%B8Ze%D8%CBP%19*Ce%A8%0C%95%D1ae%EC%F7%89I%E1%B4%D7M%D7P%8BjU%5C%BB%3E%F2%20%D8%CBP%19*Ce%A8%0C%95%A12T%C6%D5*%C3%5E%86%CAP%19*Ce%B4O%07%7B%F0W%7Bw%1C%7C%1A%8C%B3%3B%D1%EE%AA%5C%D6-%EBV%83%80%5E%D0%CA%10%5CU%2BD%E07YU%86%CAP%19*%E3%9A%95%91%D9%A0%C8%AD%5B%EDv%9E%82%FFKOee%E4%8FUe%A8%0C%95%A12T%C6%1F%A9%8C%C8%3D%5B%A5%15%FD%14%22r%E7B%9F%17l%F8%BF%ED%EAf%2B%7F%CF%ECe%D8%CBP%19*Ce%A8%0C%95%E1%93~%7B%19%F62T%86%CAP%19*Ce%A8%0C%E7%13%DA%CBP%19*Ce%A8%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19f%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%98-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA0%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95a%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%C3l%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%86%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0C%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19f%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%98-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA0%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95a%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%C3l%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%86%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0C%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%A9%0CZf%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19f%8B%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1R%19%B4%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52%CC%16-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2%A52h%99-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%98-Z%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2EKe%D02%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA0%5B%B4h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%96%CA%A0e%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95a%B6h%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-%95A%CBl%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%C3l%D1%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z*%83%96%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%86%D9%A2E%8B%16-Z%B4T%06-%B3E%8B%16-Z%B4%AE%A4%F5%25%C0%00%DE%BF%5C'%0F%DA%B8q%00%00%00%00IEND%AEB%60%82") repeat-y !important;

    border-left: 1px solid #BBBBBB !important;

    border-right: 1px solid #000000 !important;

    border-bottom: 1px dashed #BBBBBB !important;

}



.overflowRulerX > .firebugRulerV {

    left: 0 !important;

}



.overflowRulerY > .firebugRulerH {

    top: 0 !important;

}



/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

.fbProxyElement {

    position: fixed !important;

    pointer-events: auto !important;

}

</style></head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="inner">
            <a class="title" href="http://apps.sourcebits.com/cart543/index.html"><h1>Cart</h1></a>
            <a id="btn_purchase_history" title="Home" class="btn" onmouseover="className = 'btnfade'" onmouseout="className = 'btn'" href="http://apps.sourcebits.com/cart543/history.html">Purchase History</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="product_grid">
        <div class="inner">
            <h3>Choose a Product:</h3>
            <div id="selling_items" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
                <img class="" src="HTML5%20Development%20_%20CSS3%20Development%20_%20Shopping%20Cart%20Development%20_%20Cart%20543_files/item1.png" alt="Watch-1" id="item1" onmouseover="className = 'zoom'" onmouseout="className = ''" ondragstart="drag(this, event)">


                <img class="" src="HTML5%20Development%20_%20CSS3%20Development%20_%20Shopping%20Cart%20Development%20_%20Cart%20543_files/item4.png" alt="Watch-4" id="item4" onmouseover="className = 'zoom'" onmouseout="className = ''" ondragstart="drag(this, event)">
                <img class="" src="HTML5%20Development%20_%20CSS3%20Development%20_%20Shopping%20Cart%20Development%20_%20Cart%20543_files/item5.png" alt="Watch-5" id="item5" onmouseover="className = 'zoom'" onmouseout="className = ''" ondragstart="drag(this, event)">
                <img src="HTML5%20Development%20_%20CSS3%20Development%20_%20Shopping%20Cart%20Development%20_%20Cart%20543_files/item6.png" alt="Watch-6" id="item6" onmouseover="className = 'zoom'" onmouseout="className = ''" ondragstart="drag(this, event)">
                <img class="" src="HTML5%20Development%20_%20CSS3%20Development%20_%20Shopping%20Cart%20Development%20_%20Cart%20543_files/item7.png" alt="Watch-7" id="item7" onmouseover="className = 'zoom'" onmouseout="className = ''" ondragstart="drag(this, event)">
            <img class="" src="HTML5%20Development%20_%20CSS3%20Development%20_%20Shopping%20Cart%20Development%20_%20Cart%20543_files/item3.png" alt="Watch-3" id="item3" onmouseover="className = 'zoom'" onmouseout="className = ''" ondragstart="drag(this, event)"></div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="product_cart">
        <div class="inner">         
            <h2>Drag Here</h2>
            <div id="buying_items" ondrop="drop(this, event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">
            <img class="" src="HTML5%20Development%20_%20CSS3%20Development%20_%20Shopping%20Cart%20Development%20_%20Cart%20543_files/item2.png" alt="Watch-2" id="item2" onmouseover="className = 'zoom'" onmouseout="className = ''" ondragstart="drag(this, event)"></div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="about">
        <div class="inner">
            <div id="description">
                <p>Five stands for <strong>HTML 5.</strong> Four means <strong>Safari 4.</strong> Three is <strong>CSS 3.</strong></p>
                <p>Cart543 is minimalistic checkout module of a fictional shopping 
cart. It is powered by HTML 5 and CSS 3. It uses modern features 
implemented in Safari 4, such as Canvas drawing, SVG images, CSS 
animation, HTML 5 Sessions, Multi-step form, HTML drag and drop, latest 
HTML 5 tags etc. It uses minimal Javascript to process data from HTML 5 
form.</p>
                <p>Since most of above-mentioned features are implemented in Safari only, hence this page works best in <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/">Safari 4 Beta</a>.</p>
            </div>
            <a onclick="saveCart(buying_items);" id="btn_checkout" class="btn" onmouseover="className = 'btnfade'" onmouseout="className = 'btn'" href="http://apps.sourcebits.com/cart543/checkout-step1.html">Checkout</a>


        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <div class="inner">
            <span class="small">©</span> 2009 Cart543. <a href="http://www.sourcebits.com/web-development" target="_blank" title="Web Development">Web Development</a> by Sourcebits.
        </div>
    </footer>

<div style="left: 121.5px ! important; top: 170px ! important;" class="firebugResetStyles firebugBlockBackgroundColor firebugLayoutBox firebugLayoutBoxOffset"><div style="padding: 0px ! important; background-color: rgb(237, 255, 100) ! important;" class="firebugResetStyles firebugLayoutBox"><div style="padding: 0px ! important; background-color: rgb(68, 68, 68) ! important;" class="firebugResetStyles firebugLayoutBox"><div style="padding: 0px ! important; background-color: SlateBlue ! important;" class="firebugResetStyles firebugLayoutBox"><div style="width: 1020px ! important; height: 17px ! important; background-color: SkyBlue ! important;" class="firebugResetStyles firebugLayoutBox"></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>
```

**CSS**

```
/* @override http://sbnew.publishy.com/cart543/v2/css/reset.css */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------- 

   reset.css
   * Resets default browser CSS.

-------------------------------------------------------------- */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, code,
del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
body { 
  line-height: 1.5; 
}
/* Tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup. */
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }
caption, th, td { text-align: left; font-weight: normal; }
table, td, th { vertical-align: middle; }
/* Remove possible quote marks (") from <q>, <blockquote>. */
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ""; }
blockquote, q { quotes: "" ""; }
/* Remove annoying border on linked images. */
a img { border: none; }
```

**More CSS**

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";






/**
 * Project: Cart543
 * Date of creation: March 6, 2009;
 * Last Update: March 16, 2009;
 */

@font-face {
    font-family: "PF DinDisplay Pro Light";
    src: url('../fonts/PFDinDisplayPro-Light.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "PF DinDisplay Pro Regular";
    src: url('../fonts/PFDinDisplayPro-Reg.ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "PF DinDisplay Pro Thin";
    src: url('../fonts/PFDinDisplayPro-Thin.ttf');
}

body {
    font: normal 12px "PF DinDisplay Pro Light", Tahoma, Helvetica, "Myriad Pro", Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif, "Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS";
}

body {
    background: #ff3000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2, h3, .user-input, label, .btn, .btnfade {
    font: normal 12px "PF DinDisplay Pro Regular", Tahoma, Helvetica, "Myriad Pro", Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif, "Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS";
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#btn_purchase_history, #btn_checkout, #btn_return, #btn_ok {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 200px !important;
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform, background-color, 1s, ease-in 300ms;
}

.btn, .btnfade {
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 100px !important;
    padding: 5px 10px 0 10px !important;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #ff3000;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: solid 1px #ff3000;
}

.btnfade {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #ff3000;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform, background-color, 1s, ease-in 300ms;
}

#btn_purchase_history {
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 90px;
}

#btn_checkout, #btn_return, #btn_ok {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#btn_ok {
    width: 222px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #ff3000;
}

header h1 {
    font: normal 12px "PF DinDisplay Pro Thin", Tahoma, Helvetica, "Myriad Pro", Verdana, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif, "Century Gothic", "Trebuchet MS";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 129px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 458px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url(../images/543.svg) no-repeat right 18px;
}

.title {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mac header h1 {
    background: url(../images/543.svg) no-repeat right 17px;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    line-height: 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #fff;
    background: #ff3000;
}

strong {
    background: #fff;
    color: #ff3000;
    padding: 4px 4px 0;
}

.small {
    text-transform: lowercase !important;
}

section, header, footer {
    display: block;
}

.inner {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1020px;
    position: relative;
}

header {
    display: block;
    height: 160px;
}

header .inner {
    background: url(../images/arrow-top.png) no-repeat 880px bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

#logo {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#product_grid {
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: auto;
}

#product_grid .inner {
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #40e1b2;
}

.user-input {
    color: #11a479;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#product_grid .inner h3 {
    color: #ff3000;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#selling_items {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 35px 0 0 0;
    min-height: 220px;
}

#selling_items img, #buying_items img {
    margin: 0 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.zoom {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
}

#product_cart {
    background-color: #40e1b1;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

#product_cart .inner {
    background: url(../images/arrow-bot.png) no-repeat center top;
    padding: 25px 0 0 0;
}

#product_cart .inner h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

#buying_items {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 180px;


/*

background-color:#000;*/
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#about {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

#about .inner {
    background: url(../images/arrow-bot-green.png) no-repeat 880px top;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}

#description {
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: newspaper;
}

/**
 * Checkout form * 
 */

label {
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px;
}

input, textarea {
    width: 250px;
    padding: 2px 0 2px 5px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
}

textarea {
    height: 120px;
}

.form_checkout {
    width: 450px;
    color: #40e1b1;
    float: left;
}

.form_checkout p {
    overflow: hidden;
}

p#details, p#address {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

footer {
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

I've ran out of space but you just need the two other JQuery files called main.js and jquery-1.js

Comment: Hello I tried your method but turns out it's not what I wanted.. I need an item to be dragged to the green box but still remains in the white box. It's something like a drag and copy but I also don't want it to be a multiple copy when i keep dragging it.

Comment: @JosLuciette Using the method I stated above I would add a jquery if statement that will prevent other items from being placed in that area. I would still use that code as a boiler plate. And add some jquery if statements to prevent other items from being dropped. And changing colors as you need to in the CSS